# Storing Access & Refresh tokens from multiple Providers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

Say I am allowing my users to connect to Facebook, Instagram, Pinterest & Twitter, so they can use their API's. So I get access tokens for all those providers.

From what I've read, my inclination now is to store them in a http-only cookie.

However, with 4 access tokens, *would that mean that all 4 access tokens are always being sent on every request?*

What would be a secure approach here? Or would I in this case not store them on the client at all?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact architecture of your solution. If you have a backend, and your backend calls these APIs then you can keep those tokens in your backend. They don't have to be kept in the front-end at all. If your front-end needs those tokens (e.g. it is calling these APIs directly), then you have to keep the tokens there, and they have to be readable by your frontend app (so they can't be stored in an HTTP-only cookie).

I would struggle not to have any tokens in the browser. It's best to keep them in the backend.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I have been struggling with this a lot. Would it be fine to just store them in a database, or can I use something like `node-persist`, (if you're familiar)? Also, one thing I am wondering about is, if I store them in my own backend, then I guess I will need to secure my own API to that backend myself? I am just wondering whether this won't make it more vulnerable, since now it's on me to do authentication between my frontend and backend? What do you think about that?

Comment: You can rely on a plain-old cookie-based session. That way you're using a reliable and battle-tested feature for authenticating and authorizing access, and you don't have to worry that much about your tokens being stolen from the browser with an XSS attack.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, being a beginner I have some trouble understanding how these things work. Just to make sure, do you mean that I should secure the API between client & my own server with cookie-based sessions? So I'd identify the user via the cookie bases session, and in the backend I would just save the tokens on some database somewhere, probably encrypted, and then get that users access token and make the API call?

Comment: Exactly. I think you don't have to save the tokens in an encrypted format. It will add complexity to your solution but not much real value.